# Powershell multiple line regular expression to find code blocks

Tags: regex, powershell

I need a regular expression to find all code blocks that look like the following:

single line

```
export const someSingeLine: ISomeSingleLine = { //stuff };
```

multiple line

```
    export const constState: ISomeInterface = {

       someProperty: {//other stuff}

    };
```

So far I have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.ts | get-content -raw | Select-String -pattern "export\s+const\s+([a-zA-Z])*:(.)*" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Recursively get every typescript file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.ts
```

Read the file into a string:

```
get-content -raw
```

Find the matches

```
Select-String -pattern "export\s+const\s+([a-zA-Z])*:(.)*" -AllMatches
```

Output what was found:

```
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

I have tried some other combinations, but I have not been able to match the entire multi line code block that ends with

> };

Update:
After posting this...I tried the following which I believe gets the results that I am looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.ts | get-content -raw | Select-String -pattern "export\s+const\s+([a-zA-Z])*:([^;])*;" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Comment: Since you are reading in a -raw, which you have to do, so also need to add some modifiers to your regex so it works across multiple lines `"?(sm)ex..` might help.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using [an actual TypeScript parser](https://github.com/ToCSharp/TypeScriptAST) for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you capture the correct number of nested `{}` pairs, use [balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition):

```
$pattern = '(?sm)export const [\w:\s]+=\s?\{(?:[^{}]|(?<scopeEnter>\{)|(?<scopeLeave-scopeEnter>\}))+(?(scopeEnter)(?!))\};'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.ts | Get-Content -Raw |Select-String $pattern -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

That being said, I'd suggest using a TypeScript parser rather than regular expressions for this kind of thing